# Change Chart series formula and PREVENT chart activation

Tags: excel, vba, charts

The last line automatically activates the chart. Can I prevent this? *(I do not want to just Activate something else after the fact.)*

```
Dim chart1 As Object
Dim newformula As String

Set chart1 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
newformula = ...

chart1.SeriesCollection(1).formula = newformula
```

Comment: Hi @fletch. What is active before you set the chart's forumla? I see you said that you don't want to activate something else after, but something must have been active before. Couldn't you just set it back to whatever was active in the first place?

Comment: Joe - yes, I could do this... it just seems like it should be unnecessary. Turns out it is - see learnAsWeGo's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FormulaLocal property allows you to set the formula value without activating the chart / series

```
Sub NewChart()
Dim chart1                                      As Chart
Dim newformula                                  As String
Dim SC                                          As SeriesCollection
Dim mySeries                                    As Series
Dim STR                                         As String

    Set chart1 = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    Set SC = chart1.SeriesCollection
    Set mySeries = SC.Item(1)
    STR = SC.Item(1).Formula

    mySeries.FormulaLocal = STR
    Debug.Print TypeName(Selection)
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for!